# How to validate in javascript the below select element if empty on submit

Tags: javascript, html, validation, select

I need some advise on how to validate if the below select element is empty or not on form submit. I use a validate function that works for regular select or text elements when the `id` and `name` are in this format `id=tag` and `name=tag` but I cannot find the proper way to make it work for `id=tag[]` and `name=tag[]`:

```
<select name="tag[]" id="tag[]">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

This is the function I use:

```
function validate(){ 
      with (document.form){ 
      if(tag.value==""){
           alert("Enter tags");
           tag.focus();
           return false;
      }
return true;
}
```

So what should be the `tag.value==""` in this case?

I tired `tag[].value==""` and `tag[0].value==""` without success.

Comment: try `document.getElementById('tag')` to select the `select` also you dont need the `[]` in it's id/name

Comment: I tried as you suggest - I replaced `tag.value==""` with `document.getElementById('tag').value==""` but it does not work. Also I need the `[]` because of the page functionality - I am getting more than one select element with the same name into an array :)

Comment: This however works partially: `document.getElementById('tag[]').value==""`. There are 5 select elements with this id/name and if all of them are empty the alert occurs. However, it is enough for one to be filled it and the other four also validate. Is there a way to make it work for all 5 elements?

Comment: can you give the problem you are actually trying to solve. why would you validate your own html? is it generated?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works

```js
function validate() {
  var selectValue = window.document.myForm["tag[]"].value;
  if (selectValue == "") {
    alert("Invalid : Enter tags");
    window.document.myForm["tag[]"].focus();
    return;
  }
  alert("Valid");
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
  <select name="tag[]" id="tag[]">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>

</form>

<button onclick="validate()">Validate</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (for validateJS)

```
constraints[treatment_type] = {"format": {"pattern":"4","message": "You need 
To select Hospitalization"},"presence": {"message": "Value is required"}}
```

The object created is :

```
constraints = {
treatment_type:

format: {pattern: "4", message: "You need To select Hospitalization"}
presence: {message: "Value is required"}
}
```